# Is it safe to leave the /home folder on an SSD?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I just got a new laptop which came with a 500 GB SSD and a 1000 GB HDD. On the SSD there was a Windows 10 installation. I partitioned the SSD and now have both Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed on it. I have not moved my `/home` directory to the HDD. Since I am going to be `apt-get`ting a lot of programs, I will be writing a lot of data to this SSD. From my understanding, this is potentially a bad thing as it can damage the drive.

1. Is this a bad thing?
2. By moving `/home` to the HDD, will this mitigate the problem?

Comment: Having a ton of I/O operations on any drive is not good, but a SSD _should_ be a bit more resilient than a HDD. It seems more of a matter of choice, but my opinion is to keep the ~/home folder on the disk that has the least risk of failure, while hosting the majority of data files needed for the system to run.

Comment: Apps are in / (root). Each user has configuration files in his /home/$USER. Apps are generally not large, unless games which can be installed in /home if not shared with another user. I do create a /mnt/data partition on HDD for all my data.

Comment: @Dooley_labs: I can't find a source for that at the moment but I remember reading a meta-report on the reports of storage manufacturers and data centre operators that came to the conclusion that SSDs have about the same rate of failure. This may be different for laptop computers because they might be moved around a lot which increases the chance of damaging the moving parts inside a HDD.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I suppose it has to do with the quality of the hardware, but you have a point about the meta-reports. I'll be looking into those for future reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not a bad thing. I have been using a /home on my sdd for at least 2 years.

But I did change `/home/$USER/.config/user-dirs.dirs` so all my user directories point to my HDD. Those directories (like Downloads and Desktop are my 2 main areas where things get written and stored).

I plan for failure: my SDD has -no- personal data. If it fails I buy me a new one and re-install Ubuntu. My personal stuff on my HDD that I can not restore (so addresses, a passwordsafe, vpn stuff etc and not music, movies or sofware I can re-download) are all also on 2 USB sticks.

The 15 minutes it takes to re-install Ubuntu onto my SDD make it worth keeping the default operating system things on it.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind. How did you change /home/$USER/.config/user-dirs.dirs s.t. user dirs point to HDD?

Comment: edit the file ;-) it holds the directories for things like Desktop. It will guide itself when you open it with vi or gedit

Comment: oh and 3rd party apps: IF you use them those often have their own directory for storing temp files. Toss that on the hdd too.

Comment: By third party apps do you mean apps that aren't in the default repos?  Things I'd need to add to sources.list or for which I need to download the .deb files? (like Chrome?)

Comment: Yes. so not the deb installs but source or pre-compiled. "chrome" "jasperserver" "aptana" and there are more examples.

Comment: I guess this is something I'd have to do on a case by case basis? As in, I'd have to check if the app does store temp files? Is the reason I don't need to do this for non third party apps because non-third party apps will store temp files in one of the user-dirs.dirs directories by default?

 (Sorry for the never ending stream of questions; this is quite new to me!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36425/discussion-between-orrymr-and-rinzwind).

Answer (score -2):

If I may say something about this, having done an upgrade to an SSD on a MacBook Pro, I have the OS (Mac OS X Snow Leopard) on the SSD and my /Users folder on an HDD.

It is best to have the /home folder on a separate hard drive (external for laptops and internal for desktops) rather than on the SSD. Why? An SSD has a limited number of times that you can write to it and having your /home folder on the SSD is a bad idea, an SSD will actually die because it's being written to (saving your data) constantly.

Swap is another thing you don't want to have on an SSD, for the exact same reason as the /home folder. Swap as most of us know, is used for putting the computer to sleep, it saves the data to the hard drive in the /swap partition. So, if you have an SSD and have swap enabled, remove it from the SSD, move it to the hard drive or better yet, turn it off.

Comment: Since a few years an exhaustion of the state change capability of flash cells (the ability to (over-)write data) in SSDs has not been a real issue. While flash cells still fail after some time all drives (except for some really cheap USB flash drives) have reserve cells that they will use to transparently “replace” the exhausted cells. They are designed to last decades even when writing hundreds of gigabytes per day to them. Write exhaustion is nowhere near the most likely reason why SSDs die.

Comment: That being said, I have my swap partition on an SSD but I keep `/home` on a hard drive because it's bigger and easier to organise my files that way. Files in the home directory aren't typically as critical to performance as system files and fast main memory either.

Comment: I'd forgive someone for spreading this misinformation in 2012 but to be spreading this myth in 2016 or even 2018 (last edit by Netdude21) is just dishonesty or ignorance.  By all means write constantly to your SSD for hours every day and it will still last years with no single issue.  You'd have to dig deep in someone's junk shed to find an SSD old enough to be susceptible to this issue, and chances are it'll be a whopping 40GB or something and will have cost something like $900 when new.

Comment: Another slight issue is that the purpose of swap isn't for putting the computer to sleep.